# Difference between a Desktop application and a Web application

Tags: unit-testing, testing, web, tdd

What is difference between a Desktop application and a Web development application? What is Testing Strategy for a web site/web application?

Comment: The difference is they run on completly different platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will briefly share some of my experiences, as they may help establish a foundation for you.

The main differences that I have encountered are obviously the usage of markup languages (HTML/HTML5/XML, etc), AJAX, jQuery, and javascript (well, scripting in general). Tools like .NET framework amongst others also exist. You can look those up to get a full definition of what they are and how they work together,  but they introduce a new way of problem solving in terms of building small bridges to reach the end result.

As in any application, keep in mind the user-end side of the application. Millions of people will have access to it at exactly the same time. Security is paramount with web apps. Ensure you have strong security measures tied into your page.

Aesthetics will take more precedence than with desk applications (depending on what they are). Web applications are a visual experience. You want to make sure that when you design it, fields are easily identifiable, the app is easy navigable, and easy to read.

For testing, simply save your code with the right extension and run it from wherever you saved it. Most current Op Systems know what kind of web code the file is written in and will open it in a browser.  Say if you wrote "myPage.html" and saved it to your desktop, you will see an HTML icon that says "myPage". If you need to make changes, edit your code, re-save it, then simply refresh your web browser.

I know this is a very very general answer but I'm attempting to brush upon everything that I've experienced over the summer. Hopefully this is helpful, or atleast brings some considerations to mind when designing your web app. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Sir for your answer it rely helpful to me